# Trying to add a mapbox map to my tablelayout but when called the map is not displaying

Tags: java, android, mapbox, display

**Else block called when mapbox map should be drawn, link to mapbox apihttps://docs.mapbox.com/**

```
else{
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    TextView tdRow = new TextView(getApplicationContext())
```

**Created map is meant to be added to already created table**

```
 Mapbox.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.MapSDK));
 MapboxMapOptions options = MapboxMapOptions.createFromAttributes(this, null)
                            .camera(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                            .zoom(12)
                            .build());
                    // create map

 MapView mapView = new MapView(this, options);

 tr.addView(mapView);

 table.addView(tr);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a map view programmatically, in which case I would recommend modelling your implementation off of this [dynamically build a map view example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/dynamically-build-a-map-view/).

It seems problematic that you don't have an `onCreate` method -- you might need to run `mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` even without using `getMapAsync (mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {)`.

If this doesn't help, can you say more about what is actually going wrong? Did the map not show up at all? Are there any log messages or crashes? Where is the code executing in the architecture of your application? Is there a reason for you to dynamically load the map view instead of just specifying it via the XML? I hope the answers to these questions can help reach a resolution!